# Concatenated data from pandas_datareader

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to create a dataframe which columns from 2 different datarame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels import api as sm
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2016,12,2)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
df = web.get_data_yahoo(['F'], start, end)
df1 = web.get_data_yahoo(['^GSPC'], start, end)
df3 = pd.concat([df['Adj Close'], df1['Adj Close']])
```

With this i wanted to get `df3` with 2 columns containing data of [Adj Close]. What i got instead is :

```
    F   ^GSPC
Date        
2016-12-01  10.297861   NaN
2016-12-02  10.140451   NaN
2016-12-05  10.306145   NaN
2016-12-06  10.405562   NaN
2016-12-07  10.819797   NaN
... ... ...
2019-11-22  NaN 3110.290039
2019-11-25  NaN 3133.639893
2019-11-26  NaN 3140.520020
2019-11-27  NaN 3153.629883
2019-11-29  NaN 3140.979980
1508 rows × 2 columns
```

What do i need to do to get rid of NaN values and why is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `axis=1` for concanecate by columns in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df['Adj Close'], df1['Adj Close']], axis=1)
```

But I think your solution should be simplify with pass list to `get_data_yahoo`:

```
df3 = web.get_data_yahoo(['F', '^GSPC'], start, end)
```

Comment: It worked!!! I would have thought it is default behavior Why would one need to specify  'along the columns'. I can see if someone needed to do axis =0

Comment: @newcoder - Default behaviour is `axis=0` for concanecate  by index

Comment: `df3 = web.get_data_yahoo(['F', '^GSPC'], start, end)` i am not using as you had suggested because i am going to use a for loop on just `df` and then concatenate it with `df2`